# CSS issue in a master page of asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

When i added following `css` file and menu control to the existing master page, we are not able to see the menu control in UI, were in the sense when  i created new project which doesn't have master page added these CSS i can see the menu control, any body has any idea?CSS is as follows

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.hideSkiplink {
        background-color: #3a4f63;
        width: 100%;
    }
    div.menu {
        padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
    }
        div.menu ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: auto;
        }
            div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited {
                background-color: #465c71;
                border: 1px #4e667d solid;
                color: #dde4ec;
                display: block;
                line-height: 1.35em;
                padding: 4px 20px;
                text-decoration: none;
                white-space: nowrap;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
                div.menu ul li a:hover {
                    background-color: #bfcbd6;
                    color: #465c71;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                div.menu ul li a:active {
                    background-color: #465c71;
                    color: #cfdbe6;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:Menu ID="dynamicMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu"   EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

No luck as of now ,,@script1004 expected; i am getting and i am not able to see the menu, if i delete some css file i can see menu without child nodes.I doubt whether it is due to HTML5 convertion issue or something

Comment: Look like you might have solved the problem yourself. You just need to view the browser source of those two pages. It seems that master page have some tags or css which makes the menu not visible.

Comment: No luck as of now ,,@script1004 expected; i am getting and i am not able to see the menu, if i delete some css file i can see menu without child nodes.I doubt whether it is due to HTML5 convertion issue or something